# Magento Disable auto state "complete" for Virtual Orders

Tags: magento, state

I sell only virtual products, and when the order is paid the state is automatically set to "Complete" as there is no shipping for virtual products. However, i would like the state to remain on "Proccessing" as i want to set the state "Complete" manually after reviewing..

How can I achieve this?

[state http://www.bindemo.se/state.PNG](http://www.bindemo.se/state.PNG)

Comment: It is possible to change line 725 in /app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php. but I don't feel good changing Magento Core.: if ($this->getIsVirtual() || $this->isCanceled()) {
            return true;

Comment: this is what i want ..have you done it ?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out without editing core?